# Variable dependency in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I'm using RequireJS to load my JavaScript modules for a BackboneJS web app, but I'm running into a style issue at the moment.

I have two classes that share a LOT of code, but they both subclass different classes.

```
TemplateLessonView                         LessonView
        |                                      |
        |                                      |
    EditorApp    <-- these share code -->    MainApp
```

Now to keep things DRY I'd like `MainApp` to extend `EditorApp`, but then `EditorApp`'s dependencies are loaded and `EditorApp` calls some of it's base class' functions by means of this format: `this.constructor.__super__.initialize.apply(this);`

A solution would be to change EditorApp's dependencies when the module is loaded from `MainApp`'s module (so I would require `LessonView` but pass it to `EditorApp` as `TemplateLessonView`.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, or has another suggestion to accomplish what I'm trying here?

Comment: If they share code, how about moving it into a mixin and let both objects share that?

Comment: It seems like, as Simon suggests, you might actually want to extract the common code from from EditorApp and MainApp , and let them share this code (either by inheriting it, by mixing it in, or by using composition rather than inhéritance.) Hard to tell without any code from your classes... could you post some ?

Answer (score 0):

On way to solve this is to create a module that you will import in both class definition...

something like that :

```
(...require stuff ...)
return {
    myfct1 : function(){
    },
    myfct2 : function(){
    }
}
```

and then you can import the module where you need it, and then call your common code like a library...